# python: accessing global variable from a nested fucntion is another file

Tags: python, import, global-variables, nested-function

I have a read.py file that contains this code:

```
import argparse
import os
from config import data_dir
import pandas as pd


def my_func(func):
    def wrapper():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--dir')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        if args.dir is None:
            args.dir = input('Enter data directory:')
            global directory
            directory = args.dir
            path = os.path.join(data_dir, os.path.join(directory, 'new.csv'))
            data = pd.read_csv(path)
            return data
        func()
        return wrapper

@my_func
def another_func():
if not any(fname.startswith('car') for fname in os.listdir(data_dir)):
    print('directory is empty')

another_func()
```

it takes an argument from the user and reads the data from the directory given. the my_func function is a wrapper that wraps another function as shown in the code. what I would like to do is to import the global variable directory in another python file new.py. so in the file i have tried:

```
import read
read.my_func()
read.directory
```

but I obviously get the following error:

```
TypeError: my_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right function? Because when you declare `my_func` you already specify it needs to have 1 parameter when called

Comment: the my_func is a decorator, and takes another_function as func. however, in the new.py file I am not sure what I should declare to access the variable 'directory'. I thought buy declaring it global, I might be able to access that, but it did not work

Comment: If you want want to call `read.my_func()` you need to pass another function like `read.my_func(foo)` first

Comment: I actually would like to have access to the 'directory' variable inside the wrapper function rather than read.my_func(), but for non_nested functions i would do what you mentioned, however in this case I do not know how to access that variable

Comment: I think you can add another line at the top of `read.py` like `directory=None` then in `new.py` try using `read.another_func()` instead of `read.my_func()`

Comment: yes, that solved the issue. thank you